# Why does a file update sometimes return drive:v1 as the file id?

Tags: google-drive-api

After many successful file updates, there was one update where the returned file id was drive:v1 instead of a valid file id. Also, the request in question took 10 seconds (usually it's under one second) according to the App Engine logs and not because of App Engine instance startup time which is very odd.

The code I used is based on the Google Drive SDK Python example app, DrEdit and is only slightly modified (I added Base64 encoding because I transfer tiny images, not text).

To be more specific, in the sample code in the put method in the ServiceHandler class, this piece of code is supposed to return the file id after updating a file:

```
# Respond with the new file id as JSON.
  self.RespondJSON(resource['id'])
```

This worked lots of times, but one time it returned drive:v1. The update still changed the file correctly though, other than the file id issue, the request worked as it should.

Here is the modification I made to the portion of the sample code affected by this:

```
resource = service.files().update(
  id=data['resource_id'],
  newRevision=True,
  body=None,
  media_body=MediaInMemoryUpload(base64.b64decode(data.get('content', '')),
                                           data['mimeType']),
).execute()
```

By the way, the comment "Respond with the new file id as JSON" in the put method makes it look like after updating a file the file id would change, which does not seem to be the case. This is quite confusing and it might be a good idea to change this unless the file id sometimes actually does change after an update.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried, but I can't reproduce this. Is there any way you can get a sample that reproduces it regularly?

Also, thanks for raising the issue about the comment, I will update that right now.

Edit: comment updated in http://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/detail?r=233b6db987f633ff34929247f9045feca7550688

Comment: I don't think I can provide a sample that reproduces this since the request that triggered this wasn't special in any way and worked fine numerous times before. The long time the request took could indicate that there was some hiccup on App Engine or the Drive API server causing this problem to occur. But I will add some logging to this part of the app so that if this happens again I will be able to provide more information. It would be interesting to know for example if the other fields of the file resource also had weird values, or if it even was a file resource that was returned.